# Generic Action page for HTML form

Tags: asp.net

Help, I need to create a generic action page that accepts post data from an html form. The server is running asp.net 2 on windows 2003 iis6.

I don't want the page to post back to itself, but that redirect to another page.  How do I create the page that accepts the data from another page? Not really sure where to start here

Thanks

Comment: Not sure what you want this "generic action page" to do with form data. Can you explain? And you can always use `Response.Redirect` in order to redirect to another page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what the HttpContext.Request object is for. It is there to <strike>handle</strike>hold posted variables:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpcontext.request(v=VS.80).aspx

**Edit:** As an example

```
<form method="POST" action="someotherpage.aspx">
    <!-- form stuff here -->
    <input type="hidden" name="username" value="steve" />
    <input type="submit" />
</form>
```

Then in `someotherpage.aspx` you would use the HttpContext.Request object to grab the variables:

```
string username;

if(HttpContext.Request["username"] != null)
    username = HttpContext.Request["username"];
```

Comment: @nkuebelbeck - that or in the scripted portion between `<% %>` tags. My preference is to use code behind. The HttpContext class is available for the duration of the page lifecycle though, so you should have access to posted variables at any point.

Comment: Thanks. This should give me some momentum to at least get started. Love this forum. Thanks again.